# Python OpenCV cv2.VideoCapture(0) freeze

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

I tried to make a face detection system using dlib and opencv and use my camera to test the program but the camera always freezes for some reason.

here's the code:

```
import cv2
import dlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hog_face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
hog_face_detector

def hogDetectFaces(img, hog_face_detector, display = True):
    height, width, _ = img.shape
    output_img = img.copy()
    imgGRAY = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    results = hog_face_detector(imgGRAY, 0)
    
    for bbox in results:
        x1 = bbox.left()
        y1 = bbox.top()
        x2 = bbox.right()
        y2 = bbox.bottom()
        cv2.rectangle(output_img, pt1=(x1, y1), pt2=(x2, y2),
        color=(0, 255, 0),thickness=width//200)
        crop_img =  img [y1:y2, x1:x2]
        crop_img = cv2.resize(crop_img,(500,500))
        cv2.imshow('crop', crop_img)
        cv2.imwrite('crop/face_dlib.jpg', crop_img)
        output_img = cv2.resize(output_img,(500,500))
        cv2.imshow('detected', output_img)


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    hogDetectFaces(img, hog_face_detector, display=True)

    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: you use `waitKey(0)` - so it waits all time for key press. Use i.e `waitKey(10)` and it will wait only 10ms.

Comment: @furas note it will not necessarily wait 10ms. According to the docs "Since the OS has a minimum time between switching threads, the function will not wait exactly delay ms, it will wait at least delay ms"

Comment: Add this before waitKey() cv2.imshow('detected',  frame)

Comment: As furas suggested, you need to use `waitKey(n)` where in your case should be `n>0` as time in milliseconds to actually "give the time" to show the image right after calling `cv2.imshow()`